# Exclude resources in Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I am investigating integrating Spring Cloud Sleuth into a new Spring Boot service we are building and want to exclude certain URL's from generating spans for example health check endpoints which are polled periodically.

Checking the code I can see that the TraceFilter created in the [TraceWebAutoConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/f48fc040495c1b40cd841b83e54b3d1deef3e4f3/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebAutoConfiguration.java) has a DEFAULT_SKIP_PATTERN which can be overridden by setting `spring.sleuth.instrument.web.skipPattern`.

However even if I access a resource under the DEFAULT_SKIP_PATTERN I am still observing that a trace & span are being created i.e.

```
17:28:46.142 [XNIO-2 task-1] INFO  o.s.c.sleuth.log.Slf4jSpanListener - Starting span: MilliSpan(begin=1454394526140, end=0, name=http/info, traceId=908b24a3-143f-4949-8f86-5df867e3985b, parents=[], spanId=908b24a3-143f-4949-8f86-5df867e3985b, remote=false, exportable=false, annotations={}, processId=null, timelineAnnotations=[])
17:28:46.143 [XNIO-2 task-1] INFO  o.s.c.sleuth.log.Slf4jSpanListener - Continued span: MilliSpan(begin=1454394526140, end=0, name=http/info, traceId=908b24a3-143f-4949-8f86-5df867e3985b, parents=[], spanId=908b24a3-143f-4949-8f86-5df867e3985b, remote=false, exportable=false, annotations={}, processId=null, timelineAnnotations=[])
17:28:46.146 [XNIO-2 task-1] INFO  io.undertow.servlet - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
17:28:46.146 [XNIO-2 task-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
17:28:46.170 [XNIO-2 task-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 24 ms
17:28:46.216 [XNIO-2 task-1] INFO  o.s.c.sleuth.log.Slf4jSpanListener - Stopped span: MilliSpan(begin=1454394526140, end=1454394526215, name=http/info, traceId=908b24a3-143f-4949-8f86-5df867e3985b, parents=[], spanId=908b24a3-143f-4949-8f86-5df867e3985b, remote=false, exportable=false, annotations={}, processId=null, timelineAnnotations=[])
```

Am I missing something? I am currently using 1.0.0.M4

Comment: What pattern are you using. You are aware that the pattern is a regexp and not an ant style expression.

Comment: Can you please show your configuration? It will be easier to understand what you're doing.

Comment: I tried explicitly excluding my `/health` endpoint by setting `spring.sleuth.instrument.web.skipPattern=/health`. 

Debugging through I verified that skipped is set to true internally in TraceFilter. It looks like this could be related to this issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/136?

Comment: A lot has changed since M4 as well so I would try snapshots if I were you. That issue also isn't relevant unless you are explicitly sending the X-Not-Sampled header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A skipped resource does not stop a span from being created, it only stops the data from being collected and exported. So your logs look normal to me. In snapshots you would see the "exportable" flag set to false in skipped resources.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Dave. 

I checked out the snapshots and can see that this logging has since been moved into trace scope which solves my issue with noisy logs due to the periodic calls to our health check endpoint.